# What are the pros and cons of removing exterior dentil molding?

Tags: vent, trim, soffit

My capping (or trimming) contractor will cap the wooden parts (e.g., rake, frieze, etc.) with wood grain style PVC coil. He said he will remove the existing wooden dentil moldings. He will add/cover the old vents with T-4 vinyl soffit.

I Googled it, and it seems dentil moldings are all about decorations, so it seems that removing dentil moldings will not have bad effect on my house. Am I correct?

The dentil moldings have been with this house for 25 years (I am a new owner though), and I don't want to cause any bad things by removing the dentil moldings.

I think I'd better cap fascia boards and install new soffits, but not sure if I'd better remove dentil moldings and cap the frieze boards.
(fascia, soffits, frieze boards are based on this figure: https://marshallroofing.com/all-about-your-gutters/)

Do you have any comments/advice or anything I should know before/after removing dentil moldings?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your existing woodwork looks to be painted the same as your window trim.  If you don't have a bunch of the original paint stashed somewhere, you might have to re-paint all your trimwork as well in order to get it all to match again.

Answer (score 9):

You're right that they're merely decorative. They're often a separate molding that lays over another board or molding. They can be removed or covered without issue.

I do think it's a loss of nice detail, though. It's that sort of thing that gives a house the richness of aesthetic yours has. Shame it has to go for the sake of convenience.

Comment: I'd agree that loosing the dentil molding looses some of the character and puts the house more into the "cookie cutter" category. They may be a bit hard to see from ground level, but those who know will notice them and appreciate them. OP may want to talk to his contractor about keeping/replacing them.

Comment: I think there are some options 1) capping the original dentil moldings. But, I am not sure if my contractor would do it since it will require lots of work. Even though he would do it, it must be expensive 2) in his quote, he included "vinyl dentil molding". so, this could be a better option. 3) do you think it would be a good idea to keep the original dentil moldings and frieze boards without capping, and to cap the fascia boards only (since rain shouldn't reach the dentil moldings and fascia boards)? However, in this case, I am not sure if he can install new soffits (T-4 vinyl soffit though.

Comment: My thought was indeed to cover the fascias and leave the undersides alone, but this is a personal decision for you.